# Apache Cordova with VS 2013

Tags: github, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to use Apache Cordova extension in VS 2013. but I don't have access to Git Hub site due to high risk Data leakage reason. Is it possible to use Apache Cordova without **Git Command Line** component.

Answer (score 1):

VS2013 is far too old now for developing Apache Cordova apps, you should use Visual Studio 2017 now, then install the [Tools for Apache Cordova](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/installation?view=toolsforcordova-2017), which provides all the required tools for developing and debugging.